# WSL2 Linux Mint OpenJDK 8

Tags: java, linux, java-8, linux-mint, wsl-2

I am running Linux Mint on WSL 2.  I installed OpenJDK 8 from using sudo apt a while back.
Running update-alternatives returns the following results.

```
 sudo update-alternatives --display java

java - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
  link java is /usr/bin/java
  slave java.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java - priority 1111
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/java.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java - priority 1081
  slave java.1.gz: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

Java 8 is point to the jre, but the entire SDK is installed.  When I switch to java-8-openjdk-amd64, the java versions is 8, but the javac is java 11.  If I perform an ls on /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin directory, everything is there.  Some of the entries are links to the jre which is fine.  How do I switch it so update-alternatives points to the /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/ directory not the /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre directory.

Comment: It is recommended that you use SDKMAN to install JDK, Maven, Gradle on WSL2. REF Java development environment on Windows (WSL2 + SDKMAN + IntelliJ)(https://marcinjakuszko.medium.com/java-development-environment-on-windows-10-wsl2-sdkman-intellij-584686fdea85)

Comment: You can add parameters under compilation to tell Javac that it must be compiled into JDK 8 format. `javac Main.java -source 8 -target 8`

Comment: @life888888 better is `javac --release 8 Main.java` which does not only imply `-source 8` and `-target 8` but also ensures that you don’t access newer API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comments.  I ended up finding the answer myself by Googling multiple results.  I uninstalled the openjdk-8 packages and installed the deb package for Zulu.  I then called update-alternatives to add the java directory that is not the JRE.  I probably didn't need to uninstall the openjdk-8 package, but I needed something in the Zulu java version.